# Youtube Iframe API: trigger function on particular getcurrenttime()

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, dom-events

I'm trying to trigger function(s) when `player.getCurrentTime() == 10` sec (and many more intervals like this).

I can do this with JS timing events but it's not accurate and slows my browser very much..

Is there an alternate?

Current code:

```
trigFuncAt = Array(3, 5, 7, 10);
setInterval(checkFunc(), 200);

function checkFunc(){
    if( include( trigFuncAt, player.getCurrentTime() ) ){
        DoThis();
    }
}

function include(arr,obj) {
    return (arr.indexOf(obj) != -1);
}

function DoThis(){...}
```

`player.getCurrentTime()` is a timer kind of variable it changes for every ms.

YT API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that you use setTimeout instead of setInterval, since you cannot guarantee that the time the function needs to execute is enough between interval time. Also you need to cast to int the current time. Sample code:

```
// implicit global video containing YT video
var keypoints = [1, 2, 3, 10, 15];
var updatePlayerInfo = function() {
    var played,
        i = 0,
        keypoint;
    // not ready?
    if (!video.getCurrentTime) {
        return false;
    }
    // ready!
    if (played = parseInt(video.getCurrentTime(), 10)) {
        for (; keypoint = keypoints[i++]; ) {
            if (keypoint === played) {
                // do something
                doSomething();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // throttle function!
    setTimeout(function(){
        updatePlayerInfo();
    }, 250);
};
```

Comment: That's great but I think 'var played' should be declared outside/before updatePlayerInfo function or else it gets reset every time and doSomething is called many 3/4 times per keypoint.

Comment: @ozke the played is local to the function as it will only store the current time temporarily. You can even omit that and call the parseInt multiple times.

Comment: Thanks again for your example. All I was saying if you run that code the way it is it will call doSomething many times per in each of the seconds marked as keypoints. Is that the desired outcome?

Comment: @ozke it won't do that. try it out. There's a `break` and also `doSomething` is FPO.